# Database querying with Google Dart?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, dart, database

I went through the documentation and did not find anything related to databases.

I guess this is not yet natively possible -- if not, then are there any libraries that utilize e.g. the Socket class to make it possible to connect to a database?

To be more specific, I'd like to connect to a MySQL and a MongoDB databases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [MongoDart](https://github.com/vadimtsushko/mongo-dart/) to be the first library to give MongoDB access to Dart.

Here's an example:

```
#import("../lib/mongo.dart");
#import("dart:builtin");

main() {
    Db db = new Db('mongo-dart-test');

    simpleUpdate() {
        DbCollection coll = db.collection('collection-for-save');
        coll.remove();  
        List toInsert = [
                         {"name":"a", "value": 10},
                         {"name":"b", "value": 20},
                         {"name":"c", "value": 30},
                         {"name":"d", "value": 40}
                       ];
        coll.insertAll(toInsert);
        coll.findOne({"name":"c"}).chain((v1) {
            print("Record c: $v1");
            v1["value"] = 31;    
            coll.save(v1);
            return coll.findOne({"name":"c"});
        }).then((v2) {
            print("Record c after update: $v2");
            db.close();
        });   
    };

    db.open().then((c)=>simpleUpdate()); 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

sqljocky is a [MySQL driver for Dart](https://github.com/jamesots/sqljocky).

Answer (score 3):

There is also a [postgresql package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/postgresql) on pub.

Answer (score 0):

for sql server i use a restfull client using asp.net webservices to call sql querys and return results in json.

I use a authentication in webservices and encrypt query in client and server. I don't know if this is a best option but work for all databases.